# Drupal Pager is producing POST parameters as part of the URL

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, pagination, pager

I'm not really understanding why this is, but Pager is producing paginated results like the following:

```
http://www.mywebsite.ca/reports-publications/reports/?field_executive_summary_value=&field_publication_date_value[value]&field_report_type_tid_selective=All&field_natural_resource_region_tid_selective=All&field_forest_district_tid_selective=All&field_keywords_tid_selective=All&page=1#
```

Instead of simply:

```
http://www.mywebsite.ca/reports-publications/reports/?page=1
```

Additionally, "page=1" represents the second page ... as in an array of pages where 0 is actually the first result.

Does anyone know why Pager is producing links like this?

Comment: have you exposed any filters on that page? ( not just the view for which the pager is attached )

Comment: Looks like that might be the case. But Drupal won't allow me to change the option... it's like there's an admin "block" for overwrites.

Comment: Change the ID used for the pager: The setting is under the advanced options for the view, in the administration area.

Comment: I still can't figure out how to prevent all of the filters being a part of the link...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the page number issue by altering pager.inc file.

in pager_find_page function,

```
function pager_find_page($element = 0) {
  $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : '';
  $page_array = explode(',', $page);
  if (!isset($page_array[$element])) {
    // Change here
    // $page_array[$element] = 0;
    $page_array[$element] = 1;
  }

  // Add this
  $page_array[$element]--;

  return (int) $page_array[$element];
}
```

and, in theme_pager_link function,

```
if ($new_page = implode(',', pager_load_array($page_new[$element], $element, explode(',', $page)))) {
    // Change here
    // $parameters['page'] = $new_page;
    $parameters['page'] = $new_page + 1;
}
```